# Possible genotypes for blood types?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, hematology

If I am blood type B, what are all the possible genotypes that could be expressed by my parents?

I think it might be 16 but I was reading online and saw this:

> Similarly, someone who is blood type B could have a genotype of either
>   BB or BO.

So if someone can help me answer this, that would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Parent 1 and 2 have each 5 possible genotypes** (OO, AO, BB, BO and AB).

Here a [Punnett square](http://www.moveeatlivewell.com/2012/02/blood-type-genetics.html) with each possibilities. I highlighted the possible parent genotypes.

[image]

**The total number of possible crosses is exactly 21**. Note that here A = Ia, B = Ib and O = i.

- OOxBB,OOxBO,OOxAB
- AOxBB,AOxBO,AOxAB
- BBxOO,BBxAO,BBxBB,BBxBO,BBxAB
- BOxOO,BOxBB,BOxAO,BOxBO,BOxAB
- ABxOO,ABxAO,ABxBB,ABxBO,ABxAB

This is starting from the information based on your blood type only (i.e. no information about your genotype).

Some background information. Antigen expressing alleles (here referred as Ia or A and Ib or B) are dominant. Not expressing an allele is notated i or O. Being of blood type O is when you don't express both alleles so it is a recessive trait (only possible genotype is ii or OO genotype).

Comment: You probably shouldn't call an AB individual homozygous.

Comment: @canadianer thanks for pointing that out. Modified the table.

Comment: Your answer is better, so I'll just delete mine to avoid confusion.

Comment: @poka.nandor was getting messy without a table ;)

Comment: @cagliari2005 yeah I should have done the same to avoid missing possible crossings. I feel bad about it... I mean not about you having a better answer, but about me being careless.

Answer (score 1):

21 crosses could be many more if you considered minor types as A2, A3, B3 or hybrid alleles as Ax, Bx or chimera AB alleles as cis-AB, B(A). These rare phenotypes break standard 4 type rules, for example, Ax/O genotype could be both type A or type O. It depends if you talk about genetcis or blood compatibility.